# Ignore blanks in stacked bar chart

Tags: powerbi

I need to ignore blanks in this chart.

I have tried query editor whether there are null values selected when filtering.

But it doesn't work. How can I ignore blanks in visuals?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to go to the **Filter Panel**, and in **territoryname** column, select **All** and deselect **Blank**.

Comment: Glad I could help. That's how I do it too.

Comment: I have another problem now. have a seperate column stating whether the date is a weekday or weekend.I have a calculated column which calculate the daily target and i want to remove weekend dates from the table.How can i remove weekend dates from the table?

Comment: If your column that states if it is weekday or weekend is [IsWeekDay]: weekday = 1 , weekend = 0, to get only weekdays you just need a filter like: FILTER(DIM_Date;DIM_Date[Is Week Day]=0).
I didn't understand your use case correctly, but that condition should help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks.It helps :-)